# Can't pass data from model to method in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a graph with a simple dropdown list with years and I need to pass the year whenever it's modified by the user so the graph will show that year's data.

For example, when I try to access the parameters from this method all i get is undefined:

```
fetchBarChartData({ anio, sort }) {
      var self = this;
      console.log(anio);
      fetch("https://demo8358110.mockable.io/year/" + this.anio) // insert your api call here
        .then(function(response) {
          var r = response.json();
          return r;
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          self.values = data.values;
          self.valuesline = data.valuesline;
          self.loaded = true;
        });
```

https://demo8358110.mockable.io/year/undefined

EDIT: I've added an example https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-x4z7b

Comment: Your example is a bit unclear but remove those curly brackets in the function call which are converting it into an anonymous object with data member anio and it should work.

Comment: I edited my answer with a sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in the changed year to your fetchBarChartData function:

```
 <select name="year" v-model="year" @change="fetchBarChartData(year)">
```